# jquery: On loading dialog from another page & adding it to a DIV, i need only the dialog area to be added?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

**I'm loading a dialog from another page using load. I'm trying to load it inside a DIV. Now i need only the dialog box area to be added inside my div , not the entire blank space that are present in the page from which i load the dialog. how can it be done ?**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#content').load('dialog.html');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Dialog.html

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#wrapper').dialog({
        appendTo:'#content'
    });
});

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    </div>
</body>
```

i tried `load('dialog.html div')` , but still the blank space also gets added !

Comment: empty the divs content before loading?

Comment: Can you post the Dialog.html code?

Comment: the div is empty. It doesn't have any other elements.

Comment: @KishorSubedi: Dialog.html only contain that empty div wrapper.

Comment: @shakti open the dialog in the parent page itself, remove it form the child page being loaded. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    // initialize dialog
    var dialog1 = $("#content").dialog({ 
                      autoOpen: false
                  });

    // load content and open dialog
    dialog1.load('dialog.html #wrapper').dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: Now, how can i position the dialog1 box to any part of my page ?

Comment: You can set the position of the dialog using `position` parameter. 

Like this `position: [0,28]`;

For detail please have look at the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Dialog)

Answer (score 0):

if u just want to load the "wrapper div" then use this `$("#content").load("dialog.html #wrapper");`